# How to stop node.js server with yarn

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I used windows-installed pc(called pc), and have a ubuntu-installed server(called server).

I installed Visual Studio Code, and accessed to server via vscode extension aka remote development.

and I installed node and create-react-app on server with vscode terminal.

I typed `create-react-app test`, `cd test`, and `yarn start`.

it's perfectly worked. but now here's the problem part.

how can I close the server?

ctrl-C is not worked, and `kill terminal` wasn't work too.

Comment: did you try control c twice in a row? that works for me, but I don't know why

Comment: @Tedskovsky didn't work for me, anyway thank you. I just reboot server for now....

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you are running inside Visual Studio Developer Powershell, you might need to use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd>.

I found that <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> was not doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows press ctrl + c  and then your project path should pop up.
enter in the terminal your path and yarn should be stopped running.